# View config not found for name RNSketchCanvas

Tags: android, npm, react-native, npm-scripts

To draw on image in a react native application ,I have used the below 
npm module

```
npm install @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas --save
```

To implement the module I followed the steps mentioned in the given link.

```
https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas
```

While opening the concern page in that application it Iam getting below error in the application

```
View config not found for name RNSketchCanvas
```

I used the sample code present in the npm module itself.